# tmux broken graphics

Tags: gnome-terminal, tmux

I am using ubuntu 16.04. On gnome-terminal I am using tmux.
for tmux, I am seeing some weird behavior. In case of colored arrow joining the bar there is a glitch. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Original image :

[image]

I have marked the problem in the image.

[image]

Comment: What's the output of  command `locale`?

Answer (score 0):

These triangles are not part of the Unicode standard, they are shipped by the Powerline font at some private Unicode codepoint.

You should consult with Powerline's developers to see if they can improve the exact look.

gnome-terminal renders some of the line drawing and similar characters (the U+2500 .. U+259F range) manually, rather than taking them from the font. This is done so that they align better with each other. It's been suggested to extend this behavior with a few other glyphs as well. It probably would have been already done if these triangles were standard, official Unicode characters. Alas, currently it would have to somehow first autodetect if powerline is actually being used, which is a truly nontrivial task, too much hassle for 2 or 4 glyphs.

See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=682635 for this discussion.

The best would be if you could get the Unicode consortium assign official codepoints to these glyphs. Unfortunately I don't know where/how this should be requested. Maybe first ask the Powerline guys whether they have already attempted this.

UPDATE: I've created a patch for VTE (the terminal emulator widget behind gnome-terminal and others), see at the link above.

Comment: Sir, I am new to this kind of thing. Can you please help me further to add your patch to my system?